# Android Database update

Tags: java, android, database

In my app i store my rss news in a database.When the user get into my news activity with internet i call createEnty(); method

```
HotOrNot entry = new HotOrNot(agones.this);

            entry.open();

            entry.createEntry(msg.getTitle(), msg.getagonistiki(), msg
                    .getskor(), msg.getgipedo(), msg.getDate(),msg.getgoal1(),msg.getgoal2(),msg.getDescription());

            // entry.update(msg.getTitle(),msg.getagonistiki(),msg.getskor(),msg.getgipedo(),msg.getDate());

            entry.close();
```

(in HotOrNot)

```
public void createEntry(String title, String getagonistiki, String getskor,
        String getgipedo, String date, String getgoal1, String getgoal2, String teliko_skor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DBHelper.TITLE, title);
    cv.put(DBHelper.AGONISTIKI, getagonistiki);
    cv.put(DBHelper.SKOR, getskor);
    cv.put(DBHelper.GIPEDO, getgipedo);
    cv.put(DBHelper.DATE, date);
    cv.put(DBHelper.GOALA, getgoal1);
    cv.put(DBHelper.GOALB, getgoal2);
    cv.put(DBHelper.DESCRIPTION, teliko_skor);


    try
    {
        ourDatabase.insert("osfpDB",null,cv);
    }       //ourDatabase.update("osfpDB",cv,DBHelper.ROWID,null);

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("DB ERROR ON .INSERT", e.toString()); // prints the error message to the log
        e.printStackTrace(); // prints the stack trace to the log
    }

}
```

Then,when the user gets into news activity without internet i m calling getData();

```
public Cursor getData() 
{ 

String[] columns =new String[]{DBHelper.ROWID, DBHelper.TITLE , DBHelper.AGONISTIKI, DBHelper.SKOR, DBHelper.GIPEDO, DBHelper.DATE, DBHelper.GOALA, DBHelper.GOALB, DBHelper.DESCRIPTION }; 
Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null); 
return c; 
}
```

My problem is that every time the user get into news activity with internet connection,the database writes all the data again from the beginning.I mean that if the first time there are 12 news,they are writing to the database.If the second time there are 12 news again,the same 12 news,the app rewrites them and i have 24 entries in my database and not 12 that i would like to have.So i m looking for a way to delete my database every time that the user has internet and recreate it,or rewrite the database every time....PLease help,i have been stacked here for days...:)

@Guillaume i m trying this but i m getting an empty database

```
HotOrNot entry = new HotOrNot(agones.this);
            agones.this.deleteDatabase(DBHelper.DATABASE_NAME);

            entry.open();

            entry.createEntry(msg.getTitle(), msg.getagonistiki(), msg
                    .getskor(), msg.getgipedo(), msg.getDate(),msg.getgoal1(),msg.getgoal2(),msg.getDescription());

            // entry.update(msg.getTitle(),msg.getagonistiki(),msg.getskor(),msg.getgipedo(),msg.getDate());

            entry.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can write delete * from scripts on on internet connection action.

Delete * clears entries in database, it doesn't remove tables. So, on next action you can insert what ever you want.

Comment: i have tried this public void deleteTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.delete(DBHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
} but its not working...

Comment: I personally feel "Delete" database is not good option when you your motive is refreshing the data. There is no change in table schema, so "Delete" database doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Add that on top of your `createEntry` method.

```
context.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
```

(`context` can be your activity)

It actually deletes the db file. So the next time you do a `getReadableDatabase()` (or `getWritableDatabase()`), it will be recreated.

**EDIT:** Something like:

```
// Do that when an internet connection is found:
agones.this.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
HotOrNot entry = new HotOrNot(agones.this);
entry.open();
...
```

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method deleteDatabase(String) from the type ContextWrapper

Comment: Is "agones" your activity class? then try agones.this.deleteDatabase

Comment: Please, pretty please, follow the standard SUN Java naming convention: class names starting with caps, object names without and in camelCase. Else it's unreadable :)

Comment: ok i m sorry. the deleteDatabase must be writen in createEntry method?or after entry.open() in my main class?

Comment: well it needs to be before you open the database. So I don't know what your entry.open method does exactly, but I reckon it should be just before - I edited my answer.

Comment: i have reedited my answer!!i m getting an empty database...:(

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase(java.lang.String)

Comment: i delete it but then i try to create entry so it souldn't be empty...where is the problem?

Comment: But anyway: normally, if you do things properly, when opening your db, it will trigger the onCreate of your db helper if the db did not exist (or was deleted) - and recreate your tables. So your createEntry will start with an empty database, but a proper structure.

Comment: with the reedited answer i m only getting the last item of my database(the 12th item)..

Comment: oh wait are you saying you call this piece of code for EVERY item you receive through RSS? Sorry, you need to call the deleteDatabase method only ONCE, not each time! Without your complete code it's difficult to be more precise, this was just to giove you ideas :)